# "what the business needs" vs "what is needed by the business"

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

Which of the following phrases sounds natural, idiomatic?

- *The business owner and the business analyst are having a conversation about **what the business needs***.
- *The business owner and the business analyst are having a conversation about **what is needed by the business***.

If none, then how do I say that?

Comment: both are fine to me, I prefer the active form (maybe the former is a little more formal?)